# Add Angular Material tooltip to SVG

Tags: javascript, html, angular, svg, angular-material

I would use angular tooltip to my svg file .

I'm trying to add dynamically the directive from ts file

`circle.setAttribute('matTooltip','test')`

Nothing is getting printed on screen.

It only works when I add the directive directly in the template.

Here's  a stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vgjjl?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.html)

My goal is not the show simple title but render a component inside the tooltip